# Tcl program whose behavior changes depending on a "puts" statement

Tags: debugging, crash, tcl, puts

The main question:

**How can a `puts` statement (of a hardcoded string nonetheless) affect program flow?**

---

I'm going to dive right into incomplete pieces of the code, for reasons to be explained later.

```
proc bgerror { error } {
    puts "Background error: $error"
    exit 1
}
```

Running my Tcl program, I get:

```
Background error: can't read "YPE(PROCESS)": no such variable
```

Fair enough, I thought; must've mucked up a `$` or bracket somewhere. To find the issue, I put `puts` statements everywhere and re-ran the program.

This time, however, my program crashed:

```
9526:   tclsh testProgram
 fffffd7ffeafebba waitid   (0, 253d, fffffd7fffdf4950, 3)
 fffffd7ffeaeff9d waitpid () + 7d
 fffffd7ffe635132 __1cPGetPstackOutput6Fiiipci_v_ () + b2
 fffffd7ffe634bfb App_CoreSignalHandler () + 76b
 fffffd7ffeafb7b6 __sighndlr () + 6
 fffffd7ffeaf0b82 call_user_handler () + 252
 fffffd7ffeaf0d68 sigacthandler (b, fffffd7fffdfa500, fffffd7fffdfa1a0) + a8
 --- called from signal handler with signal 11 (SIGSEGV) ---
```

Ouch.

Eventually, I noticed something extremely odd:

```
proc OnNewState { } {
    puts "foobar"
    # ...
}
```

*With* the `puts` statement, I get the crash. *Without* it, I get the original error. (Huh?!) I flipped back and forth many times to make sure it was deterministic—and it was.

Now, the reason I dove right into incomplete pieces of the code is that I wanted to focus the attention on the abstract, not the particular.

(The complete code is complex and opaque, mostly utilizing my company's infrastructure libraries, so it wasn't practical to simplify it to be understandable anyway. Furthermore, I already *know* that the issue stems from one of the infrastructure libraries, because the issue disappears when I remove a bit of code associated with a TCP publisher/subscriber stack library.)

**How can a `puts` statement (of a hardcoded string nonetheless) affect program flow?**

Even if I were to begin digging into the C source underlying the library in question, I wouldn't know what to look for.

Hoping for some experienced Tcl'ers to shed some light...

Comment: One thing I can think of is that `puts` messes with the interpter's "result object".  In theory, if your Tcl libraries somehow improperly access it, this would explain the crash.  In any case, I'd try to generate a proper backtrace of the Tcl runtime and try to get help on `comp.lang.tcl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the evidence you provide tells us that you're in a context with a SIGSEGV handler and that it was set by custom code (Tcl doesn't set a SIGSEGV handler).

Tcl's `puts` command will only affect control flow by generating an error, and that it does if either you pass the wrong number of arguments, invalid arguments, or if it encounters problems in the I/O layer (e.g., if you closed the `stdout` channel). A simple `puts "foobar"` is definitely a valid call, so the problem is coming out of the channel layer. Or you've got a non-standard `puts`; if your custom code replaced the standard version, there's pretty much anything that could happen.

So what might be happening? Well, at this stage my initial suspicion is that you've got memory corruption elsewhere in your program, and that this somehow has hit the internals of the `stdout` channel. If I'm right, you'll find it very difficult to track this one down; ***non-local crashes are always difficult to hunt***. I suggest that you use some combination of turning off that signal handler, attaching `gdb` so you can see where the crash *really* happened, and using `valgrind` to ensure that memory is handled correctly (if you're lucky, `valgrind` will point to where the problem is pretty much straight off).

Comment: Hey Donal, thanks for the helpful answer, as always. Eventually we solved this one. Our infrastructure group is careful not to mess with Tcl's internals (for fear of unintended consequences) and all our package and proc names are prefixed ``Fid_`` so I doubt ``puts`` was overridden. So it must have been a memory corruption. At some point in the code, a command was issued to "contact" another service. However it was found that later in the code, another command was internally also contacting that service, and apparently contacting a service twice is a no-no. Didn't look into why, but one day...